# Accessing field values in redux-form dynamically

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-form

I want to create a form with checkboxes next to pictures where when the user clicks on one, the picture gets another css-style. In order to do this, I have to access the values from the Field.

My problem is that I map dynamically over a reducer in my store to create the pictures, so I can't hardcode the fields. I tried doing it via the formValueSelector, but when I console.log it, I don't get any values, only functions. I really have no clue how to do this.

Already checked the docs under redux-form.com/6.4.3/examples/selectingFormValues but couldn't find a solution to my problem either.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

let UserCreationPageThree = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, previousPage, products, submitting } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12"><label className="pull-left">Apps</label></div>
        {
          products.products.products.map(product => {
            return(
              <div className="col-xs-2 app-container" key={ product.id }>
                <img className="app-circle" src={ product.image } alt={ product.title}
                     data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={ product.title }/>
                <Field name={ product.name } className="app-checkbox"
                       component="input" type="checkbox"/>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>

      <div className="btn-toolbar modal-btns">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={previousPage}>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> Back</span>
        </button>

        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}
                    className="btn btn-success">
            Submit <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

UserCreationPageThree = reduxForm({
  form: 'UserCreationForm', //same Form name for all pages
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(UserCreationPageThree);

const selector = formValueSelector('UserCreationForm');

UserCreationPageThree = connect(
  state => selector.apply(this, [state, ...state.products.products.map(product => product.name)])
)(UserCreationPageThree)

export default UserCreationPageThree;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally made it work.

I changed the connect function so that a variable "myValues" is returned, an object which contains the values of all the fields (initially returns undefined):

```
UserCreationPageThree = connect(
  state => {
    const myValues = selector(state, ...state.products.products.map(product => product.name));
    return { myValues }
  }
```

And I used this ternary function to determine whether the style should be applied:

```
className={myValues[product.name] ? "klappt" : "app-circle"}
```

Here is the full code, if anybody is interested:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm, formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

let UserCreationPageThree = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, previousPage, products, submitting, myValues } = props;

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-12"><label className="pull-left">Apps</label></div>
        {
          products.products.products.map(product => {
            return(
              <div className="col-xs-2 app-container" key={ product.id }>
                <img className={myValues[product.name] ? "klappt" : "app-circle"} src={ product.image } alt={ product.title }
                     data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={ product.title }/>
                <Field name={ product.name } className="app-checkbox"
                       component="input" type="checkbox"/>
              </div>
            );
          })
        }
      </div>

      <div className="btn-toolbar modal-btns">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={previousPage}>
            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"> Back</span>
        </button>

        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}
                    className="btn btn-success">
            Submit <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-send"/>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

UserCreationPageThree = reduxForm({
  form: 'UserCreationForm', //same Form name for all pages
  destroyOnUnmount: false
})(UserCreationPageThree);

const selector = formValueSelector('UserCreationForm');

UserCreationPageThree = connect(
  state => {
    const myValues = selector(state, ...state.products.products.map(product => product.name));
    return { myValues }
  }
)(UserCreationPageThree)

export default UserCreationPageThree;
```